# What is the electric potential difference for two spheres capacitors connected in series

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, potential, voltage, capacitance

Consider two spherical capacitors with Identical radii for the inner and outer spheres (let them be a and b). +q and -q charges are in the inner and outer sphere on Both the capacitors. Now I connect only the outer sphere of one capacitor to the inner sphere of the other . What is the potential difference of the inner sphere of capacitor 1 and outer sphere of capacitor 2? You can assume the outer sphere has thickness t if necessary.

I think this setup is equivalent to two capacitors connected in series. So I assumed the potential difference would just add up,or in other words, $$\Delta V =\frac{2q}{4\pi\epsilon_0}(\frac{1}{a}-\frac{1}{b})$$
In order to solve the problem
I assumed $q_0$ charge flows from the outer to the inner sphere through the connected wire to reach equilibrium. Then set the final potential difference Between them to be zero to find an expression for $q_0$ and then use that to find the potential difference between the capacitors . However that doesn't give me the desired result. So what is the correct method ?

Comment: Why would you think that the potentials adding would even give the correct answer? There is no reason why the answer should be that simple.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent Why wouldn't it? This is exactly what happens with parallel plate capacitors.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent 
 Well because , consider you connected  the uncharged two capacitors in series and applied the potential difference though a battery, also connected in series. Now both the capacitors must have equal charge q on each of them and equal voltage drop ( cause equal capacitance) now disconnect the battery and disconnect the capacitors.  You thus have the initial setup in the question . So isn't the total potential drop half of potential drop due to each ?

Comment: @Puk, but even in the parallel plate capacitors case, that is an approximation. In spherical capacitors, it is far worse of an approximation.

Comment: No, it will not be anywhere near that. First of all, the inner charges of the 1st capacitor, and thus the voltage difference between its inner and outer surfaces, will be unchanged. Instead, only a small amount of charge will be transferred from the inner surface of the 2nd capacitor to the outer surface of the 1st capacitor, making for two charged spheres. Those charged spheres will interact with each other, forming an infinite series of ever smaller corrections. The main effect is that you will create a dipole. It is not what you think it is.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent I agree that it is an approximation, but if the capacitors are separated by a large distance as is usually the case in practice, parasitic capacitances can be safely neglected. I don't see why the approximation would be inherently worse for spherical capacitors.

Comment: @Puk, you commented that just as I made a wider comment explaining why it would just not be the case.

Comment: @naturallyIncosistant Then what is  the difference between this and say two parallel plate capacitors or say two batteries ?? Why do you then assume that potential difference doubles when two batteries are connected in series? Can't I just model the batteries as spherical capacitors with very very high capacitance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, you want the capacitance $C$ between the inner and outer spheres to be large, requiring $b$ to be only slightly greater than $a$. If $C$ is much greater than the capacitance $C_{10}\approx 4\pi\epsilon_0b$ between the outer sphere and "infinity", yes, the potential difference across each capacitor will still approximately be $q/C$, and the total potential difference is twice this as you assume.

[image]

If the capacitance of the outer sphere is not negligible, or if the two capacitors are close enough to interact (such that their parasitic capacitance $C_{12}$ is large compared to $C$), some charge $q'$ flows from capacitor 2's inner sphere to the outer surface of capacitor 1's outer sphere. $-q'$ then appears on the outer surface of capacitor 2's outer sphere to maintain the charge balance. The total potential difference across the series combination is then $$\Delta V=\frac{q}{C}+\frac{q-q'}{C}=\frac{2q}{C}-\frac{q'}{C},$$
somewhat less than twice the voltage across an individual capacitor. This happens because the various parasitic capacitances steal some charge away from those between the concentric spheres. I stress that this phenomenon is not restricted to spherical capacitors. In practice we can usually neglect it because $C$ is large compared to parasitics, so $q' \approx 0$.

To calculate $q'$, we need to model the parasitic capacitances $C_{10}$, $C_{20}$ and $C_{12}$. Letting $V_1$ and $V_2$ be the potentials of the outer spheres, we have
$$q' = C_{10}V_1 + C_{12}(V_1 - V_2)$$
$$-q' = C_{20}V_2 + C_{12}(V_2 - V_1).$$
Using $V_1 - V_2=(q-q')/C$ and $C_{20}=C_{10}$, we get
$$q' = \frac{C_{10}/2+C_{12}}{C+C_{10}/2+C_{12}}q.$$

There are no simple exact expressions for $C_{10}$ and $C_{12}$ when the capacitors are in close proximity, but the leading terms in a series expansion are given [here](https://www.iue.tuwien.ac.at/phd/wasshuber/node77.html).

Comment: Look, let's absolutely disregard the parasitic capacitance for the time being. In that case, you say that the Total V will be 2q/C . But can you show that? Because when we connect the spheres(outer to inner) the -q charge on the inner surface of the outer sphere doesn't move. So to make the potential between the connected spheres equal, some charge has to flow from the inner sphere of the other capacitor to the outer surface of the outer sphere. But this inevitably means that the potential of the inner sphere decreases and the V of capacitor 2 also decreases. So the total V is less by my maths

Comment: @Al-AhsanAbhro *Can you show that?* I believe I have (set $C_{10} \ll C$ and $C_{12} \ll C$). You say charge has to flow between the inner sphere of capacitor 2 to the outer sphere of capacitor 1. Why? Can *you* show that the amount of charge flow has nothing to do with parasitic capacitances? What determines it then?

Comment: When we connect the spheres thier p.d. has to be 0 ,right? However the outer sphere is at potential zero before the connection and the inner sphere is at potential $\frac{q}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{b-a}{ab}$ So some charge q' has to flow from inner sphere to outer surface of outer sphere to compromise the potential difference. This does not effect the p.d. of Capacitor 1 . But in the capacitor 2 we now have -(q-q') charges appearing on the inner surface and -q' charges appearing on the outer surface of the outer sphere of capacitor 2. Now calculate the total p.d. across the capacitors.

Comment: @Al-AhsanAbhro This is exactly what I did in my answer. What do you propose determines $q'$? What capacitance is this charge stored in? I'm trying to explain that the parasitic capacitances (i.e. the fields outside the capacitors) are responsible for $q'$, as the calculations above show.

Comment: Ok so by putting the capacitors far apart we can reduce the $C_1 _2$. However there will still be capacitances $C_1 _0$ and $C_2 _0$ that may change the result.Am I right?

Comment: @Al-AhsanAbhro You are right. In practice, $C_{10}$ and $C_{20}$ would typically be small compared to the "useful" capacitance $C$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. However when we assume that all the capacitors connected in series have equal charge, this is still a caveat in that case too , right?

Comment: Do you mean more than two capacitors in series? Yes, except for the "capacitor 1", the charges on the "useful" capacitances would be less than in the case of an isolated capacitor, so the total potential difference would be less than the sum of those of individual capacitors.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150796/discussion-between-al-ahsan-abhro-and-puk).